# Add depth to nodes while iterating over lxml tree

Tags: python, recursion, tree, lxml

I want to add a depth to each node, for this I came up with the following recursive function:

```
import lxml.html

def add_depth(node, depth = 0):
    node.depth = depth
    print(node.tag, node.depth)
    for n in node.iterchildren(): 
        add_depth(n , depth + 1)

html = """<html>
            <body>
              <div>
                <a></a>
                <h1></h1>
              </div>
            </body>
          </html>"""

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

add_depth(tree)

for x in tree.iter():
    print(x)
    if not hasattr(x, 'depth'):
        print('this should not happen', x)
```

I thought this is one of the cheapest way to add the depth, so that doing it once will give all the elements the depth, and I only need to see each element once.

The problem is that somehow it does not seem to stick.... it's like the depth does not stick onto the element. Could it be somehow that iterating over the lxml tree is something generated on the spot, and thus  adding the depth does not stick?

What's going on here, and what is the cheapest way to get all the elements to have a depth?

#### Breakthrough

Using the following:

```
def add_depth(node, depth = 0, maxd = None):
    node.depth = depth
    if maxd is None:
        maxd = []
    maxd.append((node, node.depth)) 
    for n in node.iterchildren(): 
        add_depth(n , depth + 1, maxd)
    return maxd
```

Suddenly it does work. This code creates a huge list of all elements and the depth next to it (so I can sort it). Even while iterating over the original tree, *this time* they *do* have the depth. This is not efficient at all though, and I don't understand it.

**@ Maximoo**

```
tree.depth = 0
for x in tree.iter(): 
    if x.getparent() is not None:
        x.depth = x.getparent().depth + 1

AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'depth'
```

Comment: I think the reason why setting `node.depth` does not work is because the tree holds the DOM in some other data structure and only produces *copies* of node elements upon iteration. So modification of `node` does not modify the `tree` itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here.

- The first is you are trying to make your recursive function have the
  side-effect of updating the original tree. I don't think this is
  possible.
- The second is that you don't want to use Python attributes, you need
  to use xml attributes which you access using `x.attrib`.

A working piece of code could be the following (it's a bit awkward since I am continally casting depth from string to int, since xml attributes can't be integer). It doesn't use recursion, but I think that's overkill anyway:

```
tree.attrib['depth'] = '0'
for x in tree.iter():
    if 'depth' not in x.attrib:
        x.attrib['depth'] = str(int(x.getparent().attrib['depth']) + 1)


print(lxml.html.tostring(tree).decode())

<html depth="0">
            <body depth="1">
              <div depth="2">
                <a depth="3"></a>
                <h1 depth="3"></h1>
              </div>
            </body>
          </html>
```

Comment: Well, I've seen `attrib` (and also saw that it then specifically needs to be a string, not integer), but I do not want to actually edit the "html" key,values.

Comment: Oh. well if you  just want the nodes to have Python attributes you can change the code to just `x.depth`

Comment: Try it... that's the thing that does not work!  look at the maxymoo comment section in the question.